# Multiple websocket channels, single ws object?

Tags: websocket

I will be subscribing to multiple websocket channels of the same server. Writing a manager to assign the various types of updates I receive to different queues based on tags present in the Json is possible, but it would save programming time to just create a multiple websocket client objects in my app, so each websocket object only subscribies to a single channel. 
Is this a sensible idea or should I stick to a single websocket client?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct answer really depends on your architecture. However, as a general rule:

Stick to a single websocket client if you can.

Servers have a limit on the number of connections they can handle, meaning that with every new Websocket client, you're getting closer to your server's limits (even if the Websocket does absolutely nothing except remain open).

If each client opens two Websocket connections, the number of clients the server can handle is cut by half, open 4 connections per client and the server's capacity just dropped to 25%.

This directly translates to money and costs since running another server will increase your expenses. Also, the moment you have to scale beyond a single server, you add backend costs.