# What is better: Using multiple channels or Having multiple conditions in single channel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, actioncable

I am using Rails ActionCable.

I can choose between two choices mainly. One of them is to use multiple channels for different functionalities. Other option is to use same channel with multiple conidtions to create the same functionality.

Which one is better while scaling up? What are the disadvantages of relying too much on websockets (Actioncable) while building applications?

Can someone refer me some good article which explains websockets, redis caching and its effect when the application scales up.

Thanking you guys in anticiaption of positive response.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple websocket channels, single ws object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48975199/multiple-websocket-channels-single-ws-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I think the question is a duplicate of "[Multiple websocket channels, single ws object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48975199/multiple-websocket-channels-single-ws-object)", I will add a few specific ActionCable considerations just to clarify.

> Which one is better while scaling up?

A single WebSocket connection is (usually) better when scaling up.

Servers have a limit on the number of connections they can handle, which means that adding WebSocket connections per client will consume a limited server resource.

For example, if each client requires 2 WebSocket connections instead of 1, the server's capacity is cut by half (drops from 100% to 50%).

> What are the disadvantages of relying too much on websockets (Actioncable) while building applications?

Some machines run older browsers that don't support WebSockets. Also, WebSocket applications and clients are often harder to code, which translates to higher maintenance costs.

Having said that, WebSockets are a wonderful solution to issues that plagued web applications for ages and are superior to polling techniques.

All in all, I would argue that the disadvantages should be ignored since the advantages far outweigh the costs.

**However**:

Having said that, note that currently the `Actioncable` implementation is quite slow.

In fact, one might argue that the implementation is so slow that polling would be better.

Comparing [ActionCable to AnyCable](https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/anycable-actioncable-on-steroids) or the server-side [Iodine WebSocket + Pub/Sub solution](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine) would immediately highlight the fact that ActionCable should be replaced by other solutions until such time as it's fixed.

**Further reading**:

I just started reading [this article about Ruby WebSockets, Push and Pub/Sub](https://blog.appsignal.com/2018/08/28/push-and-pubsub-in-ruby.html), which seems very well written.

I also wrote an article about the main issues concerning Ruby implementations for WebSockets and how a server-side WebSocket solution could solve these issues. You can [read it here](https://bowild.wordpress.com/2018/05/01/rubys-rack-push-decoupling-the-real-time-web-application-from-the-web/).