# Regarding ActionCable, is having lots of Channel Subscriptions (but one Connection) OK for performance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, actioncable

I have pages which requires realtime updating of many user's presence status at once (like a large chat room or list of users). Can I simply create a subscription to every user appearing on the page for every other user? Or will those subscriptions consume a huge amount of overhead?

This would result in N^2 subscriptions, but only N channels and N connections.

What kind of resources could I expect "subscriptions" to require, compared to "connections" and "channels", both on the frontend and server?

Comment: Multiple channels for a single connection is better than a channel per connection model. If performance is a thing, look into AnyCable (allows you to keep your ActionCable code). [There's a nice talk about ActionCable performance solutions on YouTube](https://youtu.be/8XRcOZXOzV4).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple websocket channels, single ws object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48975199/multiple-websocket-channels-single-ws-object)